# Any way around AWS SSO CLI chained assume-role 1 hour limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, single-sign-on, amazon-iam

I'm using AWS SSO login with AWS CLI to assume role with IAM privileges. This is needed when running Terraforms that needs to create roles, etc. into IAM.

The problem is that AWS SSO CLI login already uses assumed role and assuming other role (chaining role) seems to have 1 hour limitation and there doesn't seem to be any way around this.

This is really annoying, if the role expires during Terraform operation as the state gets locked. This happens way too often.

So has anyone found a way to overcome the 1 hour limit when using AWS SSO, AWS CLI and terraform?

I guess one way would be to give all users SSO-Admin privileges but this seems bit unsafe.

Comment: None that I know of. It's a hard limit. Role chaining limits your role session to a maximum of one hour. You might consider requesting new credentials immediately prior to lengthy operations. Not ideal, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @jarmod. It lead towards tool called aws-vault. It's not perfect solution but as it works with AWS SSO and the wrapper assumes role every time it's run, it gives the 1 hour every time, which is enough in most of my Terraform needs.